# what is happening to this piece of code in this recusion program?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, iteration

I'm working on a assignment and I was given help on here that had a piece of code that I needed. The program works fine but there is just one part of it I do not understand.

```
public class largest_in_array 
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int array [] = {23,35,67,76,34};
            System.out.println("The largest number in the array is: ");
            System.out.println(array[largest(array, 0, 0)]);
        }

        public static int largest(int array[], int maxIndex, int i)
         {
                int ans = 0;

                if(i == array.length-1)    
                {
                    ans = maxIndex;
                }
                else     
                {
                    ans = largest(array, (Math.max(array[maxIndex], array[i]) == array[maxIndex]) ? maxIndex : i, ++i);   
                }
                    return ans;

         }
}
```

The part I don't understand is this:

```
ans = largest(array, (Math.max(array[maxIndex], array[i]) == array[maxIndex]) ? maxIndex : i, ++i);
```

It seems that maxIndex starts out as 0 and then around the third recursive step it gains the value 1. I don't know how this happens since maxIndex never seems to be incremented anywhere in the code.

I apologize if my question is confusing in advance. Any explanation of this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's a recursive function, so it calls itself every time. When you call a function, then new variables are created for the parameters of the function, and they get assigned the value of arguments. That is, if you have a function:

```
int someFunction(int x)
{
    // do something with x
}
```

And you call it like:

```
someFunction(3)
```

Then a new variable `x` is created (on the call stack) and assigned the value `3`.

The exact same thing happens in a recursive call. So if someFunction calls itself:

```
int someFunction(int x)
{
    if (x < 10) {
        someFunction(x+1);
    }
}
```

Then a new variable with the name `x` is created on every call, and assigned the value `x+1`. That is, on every call the parameter value is one higher as before.

The same happens in your code. On each recursive call, a new set of parameters are created on the stack and they are assigned values from the argument of the function call. That is, the following assignments are done on each recursive call:

```
array = array
maxIndex = (Math.max(array[maxIndex], array[i]) == array[maxIndex]) ? maxIndex : i
i = ++i
```

And therefore, `maxIndex` is assigned a new value on each recursion.

Comment: First of thank you for responding so quickly.

Second, I apologize but I still don't see where it increments maxIndex from 0.

I see "i" gets incremented, but maxIndex is only used if the equal to statement is true (to my incorrect understanding) and nothing is added to it.

Comment: I added a long explanation, hoping that helps. Even though your code has no reason to be recursive, and would be much easier to understand if it was written in an iterative way. It is still good to understand what happens during recursion.